# How to create a universal Ruby function that is callable by all of my Ruby apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built several apps in Rails, each with it's own folder structure, and I would like to create an audit trail/debugging log function that is accessible to all of them. From the initial research I've done, I believe I would have to create a function and use 'require' or 'include' to provide access to it from the current app, and it is recommended to use relative path names such as ./lib/myfunc.rb.
So, my question is: Where would I place this function so that it is accessible (common) to all of my apps, and how would I reference it using relative references?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should rather create gem out of it and add that as a dependency to your projects instead of trying to pollute the global namespace in that sense.

https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at the docs for rubygems.  I will also have to look up the reference to Global namespace because previously, I thought it referred to using Global variable names that might interfere with same-named variables from another app or function.  In my case this logging function would take 3 parameters and the scope of all of the internal variables would be local.